# Creating Raster Zones from a Polyline converted to raster

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst

I have a polyline feature class of stream gradient (SG) broken into 60m segments. This feature class has been converted to a raster, retaining the ID for each stream segment.

I also have a polygon feature class that defines the valley bottom (VB) within a watershed. This has also been converted to a raster. The cells have a value of 1 for valley bottom and NoData for everything that is not valley bottom.

My goal is to assign the the SG ID to corresponding zones of the VB Raster (perhaps using Nibble?), in order to make some measurements using zonal statistics for each stream segment.

Below is a screen capture of my project the multi-color lines are the segments and the brown is my valley bottom:

[image: screen capture of rasters]

Comment: When you say "Corresponding zones of the VB" do you mean only those raster cells overlapped by the stream raster, or the entire width of the valley bottom? If the later, what determines how you break the valley bottom into chunks? Also, if you started with two vector layers, is there a reason why you're now trying to work with them as rasters?

Comment: I'm trying to assign the segment ID to the entire width of the valley bottom. The Valley bottom, as a polygon, does not have any zone breaks in it. Was hoping I would be able to break the the valley bottom raster into zones using nearest neighbor/Nibble or something like that. That's why I'm working in raster format.  if the stream/valley bottom was more uniform, I would have just flat buffered my vector features to create the zones, but there are a lot of twists & turns and too much overlap.

Comment: Could you turning the stream lines into points and then try Thiessen polygons? https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000015377

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Euclidean allocation tool , masking by your valley bottom. This will assign each cell the id of the nearest raster segment lines within the valley bottom extent.

Comment: This was so much easier than what I was attempting to do. Thank you so much!